# Which one is the right morphism in the following exact sequence: $0\to A^{r-1}\to A^r\to A\to 0$

Tags: notation, proof-explanation, modules, exact-sequence

The following is taken from: $\textit{Partial Differential Control Theory Vol 1: Mathematical tools}$ by J F. Pommaret

$\color{Green}{Background:}$

$\textbf{Definition 1.50.}$  $M$ is call a $\textit{free module}$ if it has a $\textit{basis},$ that is a system of generators linearly independent over $A.$  When $M$ is free, the number of generators in a basis is called the $\textit{rank}$ of $M$ and does not depend on the basis if it is finite.  Indeed, if $\{x_i\}$ and $\{y_j\}$ are two bases and $y_j=\sum {a^i}_jx_i,$ then $\text{det}({a^i}_j)$ must be invertible in $A.$ If $M$ is free of rank $n,$ then $M\cong A^n.$

$\textbf{Lemma 1.54.}$  In a short exact sequence of modules:

$$0\to M'\xrightarrow{f}M\xrightarrow{g}M''\to 0$$

the module $M$ is noetherian if and only if the momdules $M'$ and $M''$ are noetherian.

$\textbf{Proposition 1.55.}$  If $A$ is a noetherian ring and $M$ is a finitely generated $A-$module, then $M$ is a noetherian module.

> $\textit{Proof.}$  Applying the preceding lemma (Lemma 1.54) to the short exact sequence $0\to A^{r-1}\to A^r\to A\to 0$ where the right epimorphism is the projection onto one factor, we deduce by induction that $A''$ is a noetherian module.  Now, if $M$ is generated by $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ then there is an epimorphism $A^n\to M:(1,0,\ldots,0)\to x_1,\ldots,(0,\ldots,0,1)\to x_n.$ According to the preceding lemma, $M$ is a noetherian module too.

$\color{Red}{Questions:}$

Can someone help me with the beginning of the above proof, I am not clear on which right morphism the author is referring to in the sentence:  "Applying the preceding lemma (Lemma 1.54) to the short exact sequence $0\to A^{r-1}\to A^r\to A\to 0$ where the right epimorphism is the projection onto one factor..."

Thank you in advance

Comment: Any of the $r$ projection maps could be used for the map $A^r \to A$. If the epimorphism $A^r \to A$ projects onto the $i$th coordinate, then the monomorphism $A^{r-1} \to A^r$ must then insert a $0$ in the $i$th coordinate, i.e., it maps $(a_1, a_2, ..., a_{r-1})$ to $(a_1, a_2, ..., a_{i-1}, 0, a_i, ..., a_{r-1})$.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang when it says the right morphism is the projection onto one factor, I can choose either $A^{r-1}\to A^r$ or $A^r\to A$ and also from either one of these two maps I have chosen, I can just choose a component from $x_i$ in $(x_1,....x_{r-1})$ for $A^{r-1}\to A^r$ or a $x_j$ from $(x_1,....x_{r-1},x_r)$ for $A^r\to A$ to project onto the range?